# Vaadin TreeTable showing empty fields after scrolling

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, treetable

I'm having problems using TreeTable: in fact does not always show all data fields after scrolling.

I used a HierarchicalContainer where:
'Codice','Gruppo','RPN' Properties are Strings
'Titolo' Property is Label
As shown in [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFN4q.png) 'Titolo' field value is not always correctly rendered.

I tried using refreshRowCache() method but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Luca

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. 1) what values do those entities have for the corresponding fields? 2) show us some code, a [short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) aka SSCEE on github or similar (even here if it fits a class or two) might speed things up. 3) use @username when replying to someone's comment so they get notified

Comment: Hi @morfic, all treetable fields are defined in AttivitasHierachicalContainer() class. The constructor of this class is: `public AttivitasHierachicalContainer() {
  addContainerProperty("ID", Long.class, 0);
  addContainerProperty("Titolo", Label.class, null);
  addContainerProperty("TitoloString", String.class, 0);
  addContainerProperty("RPN", Double.class, null);
  addContainerProperty("Codice", String.class, 0);
  addContainerProperty("Gruppo", String.class, 0);
 }`

Comment: This class has a method for row insert: `**public Object addAttivita(AttivitaBean attivitaBean)** Object id = addItem();Item item = getItem(id); if (item != null) {Label l =new Label(attivitaBean.getTitoloAttivita(),ContentMode.HTML);}}
item.getItemProperty("Titolo").setValue(l);item.getItemProperty("TitoloString").setValue(attivitaBean.getTitoloAttivita());item.getItemProperty("Codice").setValue(attivitaBean.getCodiceAttivita();item.getItemProperty("RPN").setValue(attivitaBean.getRPN()); item.getItemProperty("Gruppo").setValue(attivitaBean.getNomeGruppo());}return id;}`

Comment: are you sure that `attivitaBean.getTitoloAttivita()` always have a value?

Comment: Yes, getTitoloAttivita() it can't be null. This problem seems quite similar to bug https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6160 , but it was marked as solveld